# Excel Number like a certain number Replace

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, formula

Excel is trying to "smartly" change certain numbers in my formula for me.

Some of which make sense, some of which do not.

Is there a fast way I can do a number replace for any number that is close to the number I want to replace?

Example:

All these numbers I want to replace to A2:A2000:

`A8:A2006
A9:A2007
A10:A2008
A11:A2009`

Is there a fast way I can do that with control+H?

Comment: in your first formula you would lock the reference by making it absolute using the `$` notation: `$A$2:$A$2000` now as the formula is dragged/copied down or over the reference will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot about absolutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Craner's reply is the answer:

in your first formula you would lock the reference by making it absolute using the $ notation: $A$2:$A$2000 now as the formula is dragged/copied down or over the reference will remain the same. –